# Applications not opening up

Tags: 18.04

I just completed a new installation of Ubuntu today and everything was going fine. All the applications were working correctly and I had proceeded downloading many packages and whatnot. I had left it locked for a few minutes but now I find myself unable to open any applications like `firefox` and `google-chrome`. When I ran activity monitor, I was only able to see the disk system and not the CPU or other processes. Please advise on what could have gone wrong. I most installed packages using apt-get and got google chrome and atom manually. I am concerned about malware. Please advise on how to proceed.

Thanks!

PS: Terminal does work if that matters. I am not sure what other information I need to supply so please ask.

EDIT: Here is a list of errors from typing firefox; google-chrome, gnome-system-monitor

firefox:(it takes more time to report errors than the others if that matters)

```
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 18780
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinousSignal waiting for continue signal to child...
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
Bus Error (core dump)
```

gnome-system-monitor (1st time didn't open):

```
Disk I/O error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py, line 23 in crash_guard
  File '/usr/lib/command-not-found/', line 90, in main
  File '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound.py/' line 351, in advise
```

There is more, tell me if you need more; interestingly the second time I typed gnome-system-monitor it actually opened with a different set of errors. It basically is saying there is a 'dconf' error and it is unable to '/home//.config/dconf/user.X' where it repeatedly gives the same error with the string X changed...

I am thinking it may be likely that the computer internals are too messed up because while the laptop is relatively new its external hardware at least was pretty racked up; I was hoping the internals were working fine; windows wouldn't boot so I booted Ubuntu through a USB and installed the OS. What surprises me is everything was initially working fine so I am not exactly sure what the problem is...

Final Edit: For anyone else who may experience similar problems, rebooting fixed it for me (what do you know :P). In general I have realized rebooting will fix a majority of your problems so try that before anything...

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned about malware at this stage. Since you can open the terminal type `firefox` into it and report back on any error messages.

Comment: I think that it is interesting that most of the error messages come out to be different....

Comment: Rebooting somehow fixed the problem...if anyone could add that would be great.